# divide the string into 3 columns using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

I have the following lines in Jenkins console outpu along with several other text. I wanted to split the following text lines into 3 columns as shown below, and rest of the text lines in console output are not required..

```
NumberOfTestCases tier1 in https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/stat-autopilot-testcases.git are 4 
NumberOfTestCases tier2 in https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/stat-autopilot-testcases.git are 4 
NumberOfTestCases tier3 in https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/stat-autopilot-testcases.git are 4
```

| TOPDIR | URL | NumberOfTestCases |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tier1 | https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/stat-autopilot-testcases.git | 4 |
| tier2 | https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/stat-autopilot-testcases.git | 4 |
| tier3 | https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/stat-autopilot-testcases.git | 4 |

I tried as following, am confused how to add the first column info:

```
wget ${BUILD_URL}/consoleText -O ${WORKSPACE}/SomeFile.txt


sed -n 's/.*\(https.*git\)\ are\ \([[:digit:]]\{1,\}\)/\1,\2/p'
```

Comment: @anubhava yes: wget ${BUILD_URL}/consoleText -O ${WORKSPACE}/SomeFile.txt


sed -n 's/.*\(https.*git\)\ are\ \([[:digit:]]\{1,\}\)/\1,\2/p'

Comment: Try: `wget ${BUILD_URL}/consoleText -O - | awk '{print $2, $4, $NF}'`

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `sed` you might delete unwanted parts then change spaces to `,` (or any separator you wish to use), let `file.txt` content be

```
NumberOfTestCases tier1 in https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/stat-autopilot-testcases.git are 4 
NumberOfTestCases tier2 in https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/stat-autopilot-testcases.git are 4 
NumberOfTestCases tier3 in https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/stat-autopilot-testcases.git are 4
```

then

```
sed -e 's/NumberOfTestCases //' -e 's/ in / /' -e 's/ are / /' -e 's/ *$//g' -e 's/ /,/g' file.txt
```

gives output

```
tier1,https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/stat-autopilot-testcases.git,4
tier2,https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/stat-autopilot-testcases.git,4
tier3,https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/stat-autopilot-testcases.git,4
```

Explanation: I remove parts which are not desired in output: NumberOfTestCases, in, are, then remove traling spaces ( `*$`) then replace all spaces using `,` (feel free to adjust to any character you need in output). **Disclaimer**: this solution assumes that there is never space inside URL.

*(tested in GNU sed 4.2.2)*

Comment: The text shared in the question is not the only thing in the console output, there several other text lines as well. From which I wanted to filter the lines which i mentioned in the question in 3 columns. I have tried your solution and it is not working as there is other text as well. Instead of removing unwanted text, is there any way to parse wanted text.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mawk 'sub(".",_,$!(NF=NF))' OFS=, FS='(^[^ ]+| (in|are)) '
> ```

```
tier1,https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/stat-autopilot-testcases.git,4 
tier2,https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/stat-autopilot-testcases.git,4 
tier3,https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/stat-autopilot-testcases.git,4
```

Comment: Can you please elobarate your solution. And how can we apply the above command to a .txt file.

Comment: @ManojKumar : does it work, first of all ? As for how to apply it, either send it through the pipe (aka `stdin`) or place the file name after the command like any other. Output would be sent to `stdout` as usual. I'd recommend sending it to some temp file of ur choice and making sure it's what u want instead of any in-place edit solutions. I've made mistakes myself with overwrites of my own data so I know the pain that is to deal with such mishaps.